# Get list item row to wrap instead of show ellipsis

Tags: java, blackberry, listitem, blackberry-os5

I used the code below to get produce a layout that formats an image, a title and a text region in a list item.
I would like to get it to look like the Twitter apps layout - in terms of how it gets the tweet to wrap, what am I missing?

Platform details:
BB OS 5.0+

Code:

```
protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
    try {
        deleteAll();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    MyTitleField lblTitle = new MyTitleField(info.title);//extends LabelField
    LabelField lblDesc = new LabelField(info.description , LabelField.ELLIPSIS)
    {
        protected void layout(int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.layout(width, height);
        }
    };

    BitmapField bmfIcon = new BitmapField(info.icon);
    add(lblTitle);
    add(lblDesc);
    add(bmfIcon);

    int iconHeight = bmfIcon.getBitmapHeight();
    int fontHeight = Font.getDefault().getHeight();
    int preferredWidth = width;//getPreferredWidth();

    int startY = (rowHeight - iconHeight)/2;
    layoutChild(bmfIcon, bmfIcon.getBitmapWidth(), bmfIcon.getBitmapHeight());
    setPositionChild(bmfIcon, 5, startY);

    int textWidth  = preferredWidth - (bmfIcon.getBitmapWidth() +10 );
    int textStartX = bmfIcon.getBitmapWidth() + 10;
    layoutChild(lblTitle, textWidth  ,
            fontHeight + 1);
    setPositionChild(lblTitle, textStartX, startY);

    int descHeight = rowHeight - (startY+fontHeight+2);
    layoutChild(lblDesc, textWidth  , descHeight);

    setPositionChild(lblDesc, textStartX, (startY+fontHeight+2));

    setExtent(preferredWidth, getPreferredHeight());
}
```

[image: My code produces]

[image: The desired effect]

Comment: can't you get rid of the ELLIPSIS style here: `LabelField lblDesc = new LabelField(info.description)`

Comment: Yeah, I can, but it just runs all the way off and doesn't wrap.

Comment: can you tell me which version of JDE i have to download for blakberry-os5 development?. i can't find it by googling

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you need to get rid of ELLIPSIS style as icchanobot suggested.
2. Then you need to add your label field inside a `VerticalFieldManager` (`HorizontalFieldManager` will work too) as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6435717/396949) answer.

The following code snippet

```
String longString = "This is a LabelField inside a VerticalFieldManager. Here is a link to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641753/get-list-item-row-to-wrap-instead-of-show-ellipsis";

VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Manager.NO_HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);
vfm.add(new LabelField(longString));
add(vfm);
```

produces

[image]